# Angularjs unable to pass $routeParams to create action of a $resource

Tags: angularjs

`employee.service.js`

```
angular.
  module('core.employee').
  factory('Employee', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
      return $resource('http://127.0.0.1:8007/api/business/:businessId/employees/:employeeId', {}, {
        query: {
          method: 'GET',
          params: {businessId: '', employeeId: ''},
          isArray: true
        },
        create: {
          method: 'POST',
          params: {businessId: '', employeeId:''}
        },
      });
    }
  ]);
```

And inside my controller:

```
    self.employees = Employee.query({businessId: $routeParams.businessId}, function(employees) {

    });
    self.create = function(){
      Employee.create({
        businessId: $routeParams.businessId,
        email: self.email,
        access: self.access.value
      }).$promise.then(function(employee) {
        self.errorMsg = "";
        self.employee = employee;
      }, function(errResponse) {
        console.log($routeParams.businessId);
        self.errorMsg = errResponse["data"];
      });
    }
```

currentUrl: `http://127.0.0.1:8007/businesses/1/employees/create`

I was able to `query` employees. But unable to `create`. The error thrown is:

> angular.js:13018 POST http://127.0.0.1:8007/api/business//employees/ 404 (Not Found)

The actual url for posting data should be: `http://127.0.0.1:8007/api/business/1/employees/`

Here the `businessId` appears to have not passed to the resource. But inside the function handing the error message: `console.log($routeParams.businessId)` gives `1`.

The route inside `config`:

```
when('/businesses/:businessId/employees/create', {
      template: '<employee-create></employee-create>'
    }).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't properly wired up your `$resource` to map your request parameters to the request path.

```
$resource(
  'http://127.0.0.1:8007/api/business/:businessId/employees/:employeeId',
  // Set up default parameters to extract values from the corresponding
  // properties when the resource is used
  { businessId: '@businessId', employeeId: '@employeeId' },
  {
    query: {
      method: 'GET',
      isArray: true
    },
    create: {
      method: 'POST',
    },
  });
```

Failing to map the parameters causes the resultant request path to have fragments absent.

[The documentation for the default parameters arguments mentions this mapping behaviour:](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#$resource-arguments)

> If the parameter value is prefixed with `@`, then the value for that parameter will be extracted from the corresponding property on the data object (provided when calling actions with a request body).